# cakephp find records last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, timestamp, cakephp-2.2

How can I find the Users that are "last_seen" the last 24hours?

```
[User][last_seen] => 2012-08-18 08:10:31
```

last_seen is updated each time a logged in user browse the website with current timestamp

This is what I have tried this far:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('User.last_seen >' =>'BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW()- INTERVAL 24 HOURS'),'recursive'=>-2));
```

But my array is coming back empty.

Suggestions??

As always!! You are awesome! Thanks for your time!

-Tom

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'User.last_seen BETWEEN NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW()'
    ]
);
```

Comment: recursive -2 is meaningless, dont need lower then -1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $users = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.last_seen BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours'))
            )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Hi.. also coming back empty :(

Comment: maybe no one was last_seen between now and tomorrow, thats what above code looks for, will always return 0 users, cant last see in future